# RSA Cryptosystem

Tags: rsa, secure-storage

This question is regarding the RSA cryptosystem.

> Alice gives Bob her public key, $N$ and $e$, on a USB flash drive. Unfortunately, Bob loses the flash drive on the train.
>
> **Question 1:** Does Alice need to generate a new key pair? Justify your answer.
>
> After hearing of Bob’s carelessness, Alice sends her public key to Bob in an unencrypted email.
>
> **Question 2:** Explain how Eve, with the ability to intercept and modify messages, could eavesdrop on their conversations without either of them knowing. Why would this not be a problem if Bob hadn’t lost the flash drive?

Could I have help in answering these questions.

This is my thought on question 1: I would think Alice does not need to generate a new Public Key, since if anyone picks up the flash drive they still do not know the Private key which is difficult to determine with just $N$ and $e$. They can send Alice messages, but can't decrypt the ciphertext sent to Alice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51961/discussion-between-mikeazo-and-hogg).